# Dispatch library on Android

Tags: android, scala, sbt, proguard

Trying to build an Android app via SBT, I find that I can `android:package` just fine unless I add `"net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2"` in to `libraryDependencies`. If I add it, then I get the following (extremely long) Proguard error ([full text](https://gist.github.com/pscollins/1a11e6b2506d8454b26c)):

```
Note: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil: can't find dynamically referenced class java.nio.DirectByteBuffer
Note: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.misc.Cleaner
Note: there were 2 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
Warning: there were 1828 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 7 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 8 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
```

preceded by a few thousand lines. `android:compile` works fine with or without Dispatch added.

Looking at the [`dispatch-classic`](http://dispatch-classic.databinder.net/Dispatch+in+Android.html) docs suggests that Dispatch does not work well with Android, but mentions that the "future move to a different backend" (presumably implemented in the latest versions of dispatch) will rectify this.

I can't find any information about Dispatch and Android other than what's available for `dispatch-classic`.

Does the issue still exist? Should I just use a different library? Is it possible to modify my `proguard-sbt.txt` to make sure `android:package` can run?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Dispatch now plays nicely with Android. My issue previously was that, unknown to me, my proguard settings were being re-generated by sbt for every compile. Adding in `-donwarn **` to my `proguardOptions` in my .sbt file fixes the above errors (although I should probably track down the more specific packages that need to be `-dontwarn`'d in the future).

With that being said, it seems that Dispatch's heavy-duty dependencies do pose a problem with the Android development pipeline: running `android:package` maxes out all 6 of my CPUs and uses > 1 GB of memory. I'm way over the 65k dex limit. I think I'll go in a different direction.